# PayPal - Scope of reward points and refunds

Tags: ios, paypal

What is the scope of integrating reward points with PayPal ? Does is support refund using reward points ? There is a section [**Adaptive payments**](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/) in the documentation which talks about refund. Is that the right place to start ? And do adaptive payments feature reward points ?